# Editing a Txt File with PHP using inputs?

Tags: php, html, file, button, server-side

I wanted to write a web-app which can edit a simple textfile on the server. The user writes a string into a form and then presses a input (button). The file should've been changed but it doesn't work.

My HTML;

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">`
<input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Enter message...">
</form>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
 $chatfile = fopen("chat.txt", "w");
$message = $_POST['msg'];
fwrite($chatfile, $message);
fclose($chatfile);
}
?>
```

It's all in one file.

Comment: Place `<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">` inside your form (or use the `form` attribute pointing to an `id` attribute of the form you want to associate with)

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can save the data in a file with just one line: `file_put_contents('chart.txt', $_POST['msg']);`